# Add a custom note in the Win 7 task bar from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskbar

Is it possible to make a batch file that adds or removes a short note to the Windows 7 task bar?
By adding a new toolbar I could simply select an empty folder named after the context of my note. But since the toolbar does not recognize it when I rename this folder I can not simply update the text in the taskbar.

So in summary I would need a batch script, that:
removes the existing toolbar
renames the folder (that's obviously the easy part...)
adds a new toolbar with a link to the renamed folder

Is this possible? Or is there maybe a better approach to creating and updating custom notes in the taskbar?

Comment: Hide the title of the toolbar and instead make it wide enough to show one file name. Then in the batch file rename that file.

Comment: Works perfect. Go ahead and post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the title:

1. hide the toolbar title (rightclick, unlock the taskbar, rightclick, uncheck `Show title`)
2. make the toolbar wide enough to show one file from the folder of the toolbar
3. rename that file in your batch file